# Nested get routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to have a nested `get` inside a `resources` block. So I have the following routes:
`/businesses/page/:page`
and
`/businesses/sold/page/:page`
But I can't figure how to make it work. Here are my routes:

```
concern :pageable do
  get 'page/:page', action: 'index', on: :collection
end

resources :businesses, only: [:index, :show] do
  concerns :pageable

  get 'sold', action: 'sold', on: :collection, as: 'sold' do
    get 'page/:page', action: 'sold'
  end
end
```

How do I make it work?
**UPDATE:**
I want the above routes to work. With my current code above, I don't get `/businesses/sold/page/:page`. They are not listed in `rake routes`:

```
            GET    /businesses/page/:page(.:format)    businesses#index
sold_businesses GET  /businesses/sold(.:format)        businesses#sold
businesses  GET    /businesses(.:format)               businesses#index
business    GET    /businesses/:id(.:format)           businesses#show
```

I'm using `page` in routes for pagination. I want to use only 1 controller for all these routes - `BusinessesController`.

**UPDATE2:**
I managed to get the routes I needed, but this code looks ugly:

```
get 'sold', action: 'sold', on: :collection, as: 'sold'
collection do
  scope 'sold' do
    get 'page/:page', action: 'sold'
  end
end
```

How to refactor it?

Comment: So, where is the problem??

Comment: Please post your results from $rake routes.

Comment: Trying to get around the ugly ?page=n stuff in the URL, which I understand the need for doing. But embedding this logic in  your routes to achieve a decorator action seems like the long way round. And although I've fixed this problem on a LAMP stack with PHP and .htaccess, I have not done it on a Rails stack, so I'm mute for now, rather than give you a bad answer, but I'm sure it's possible to construct nice DRY routes and patch up the URL on the server side so the user sees a nice clean URL.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to namespace for DRYing, but looks like this is more efficient.

```
resources :businesses do
  get 'page/:page', on: :collection, action: :index
  get 'sold/page/:page', on: :collection, action: :index
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need a resource called pages - I'm using `page` in routes for pagination. I thought about namespacing `sold` but don't know how to do it properly with `sold_businesses_path` and I want to use only 1 controller for all these routes - BusinessesController.

Comment: Ah I see. Why not use `will_paginate` or `kaminari` for pagination? That way you only need to set up the index route. Would also suggest keeping them in separate controllers as that will reduce the conditional logic in each controller.

Comment: I am using kaminari. I don't just want to use `?page=1` in url

Comment: I managed to get it working - please see updated question. But I'd love to refactor it to something prettier.

Comment: Updated approach - see whether this works. Not inclusive of extraction into concern.

Comment: `can't use collection outside resource(s) scope (ArgumentError)`

Comment: Ugh, screw the DRYing.

Comment: Thanks anyway! I'll leave it and maybe someone comes up with a better solution) It's strange to me that nested `get` isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :businesses do
  concerns :pageable do
    collection do
      get: 'sold'
    end
  end
end
```

I am not sure what you are asking but I think you want to paginate through your sold.. right?

Comment: It doesn't provide `/businesses/sold/page/:page` routes